# Mono and Stereo cables / balanced and unbalanced audio

Tags: cable, connector

Does the number of rings in 1/4" connectors has anything to do with mono/stereo.
My understanding so far is
1/4" connectors with 2 rings are balanced stereo audio and one ring is unbalanced mono audio.

Please correct if am wrong.
Waiting for the comments

thanx

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the application.  A 1/4" TRS (tip, ring, sleeve) connector can be used to carry either BALANCED mono signal, or UNBALANCED stereo signal.

Recall that a balanced signal requires three conductors:  signal+, signal-, and common.
Stereo on a single cable also requires three conductors:  left, right, and common.

So, a TRS can be either carry a balanced signal, or a stereo signal, but not both.

The type of signal is determined by what the input/output jacks you are plugging into expect, not the cable itself.

Answer (score 2):

You've gotten the basic answer already, but the flip-side is that TRS/XLR aren't necessarily always balanced. You probably won't run into unbalanced TRS/XLR in any decent store bought cable, but it's always good to have a cable tester (or multi-meter) to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

they're rings ;) you can make them anything depending on your connector. 1/4" TRS is normally mono (single channel) - balanced, like an XLR.

Read up here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS_connector#Tip.2Fring.2Fsleeve_terminology

Answer (score 0):

I inquired with one of my teacher.1/4" phono connector without a ring ie a TS connector carries a unbalanced mono signal and TRS connector carries a balanced mono signal and unbalanced stereo signal.THANX for the comments